# Matching JSON value with special characters with PCRE Regex

Tags: regex, linux, json, grep, pcre

I am trying to match the value for field password with a PCRE Regex (for use with ModSecurity).

Example input string:

```
{"username":"someuser","password":"$VS*'egrE"^87Me?.?vIiJ`+"}"}}"}"}
```

Expected Match:

```
$VS*'egrE"^87Me?.?vIiJ`+"}"}}"}
```

My broken PCRE Regex (it matches two groups instead of just the part I want):

```
^\{(?:.*)"password":"(.*?)\"\}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kraIiKwhMfY3-WjQ)

Or am I totally wrong and it is matching correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Where is the password supposed to end? Your example looks like a JSON object to me, but then you must ensure that no unescaped `"` are in there which is the case in your example.

Your regex is matching everything until the last `"}` which is what you expected it to match.

If you just want to match the value of the `password` property, you could simple use:
`^.*"password":"([^"]*)".*$`

But keep in mind that this only works if there are no `"`within your password!

Comment: I provided the expected match in my original post.  MY example was a really funky string.  Another example would be the input {"username":"foo","password":"bar"} would output "bar" (no quotes) after the regex ran

Comment: In this case I don't see the problem. You regular expression does exactly that. Your first group `(?:.*)` is a non-capturing group and therefore doesn't count regarding matches.